# org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer alternative

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am very new to android development (few hours).

I am having problem with this import:

```
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer
```

I am using this as

```
    ByteArrayBuffer bytes = new ByteArrayBuffer(hex.length() / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
        if (hex.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        String hexByte;
        if (i + 1 < hex.length()) {
            hexByte = hex.substring(i, i + 2).trim();
            i++;
        } else {
            hexByte = hex.substring(i, i + 1);
        }
        bytes.append(Integer.parseInt(hexByte, 16));
    }
```

but,It gives me this error:
can't resolve 'ByteArrayBuffer'
Here are SDK Versions I am using:

> ```
> minSdkVersion 18
> targetSdkVersion 23
> compileSdkVersion 23
> buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
> ```

All I need to know is alternative to this problem.

Using Android Studio 2.0

Answer (score 1):

From Android 23, Google removed apache httpclient. To be continue using apache httpclient, you have to add apache library to your project, else using other Api.

Comment: yeah, i knew that, and thats exactly what I am asking. How to get this library and how to add it.

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi , download and add httpcore-xx.jar as library to your project

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative:

```
public static byte[] hexToBytes(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len/2];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i+=2){
            data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```